# Disruptor performance on RHEL VM vrs RHEL installed on hardware?

Tags: virtual-machine, rhel, lmax

It seems to me that this is an important question due to the increasing prevalence of "The Cloud" and for companies that use VM's for assorted needs.

Specifically the question is: How do the Disruptor libraries perform on a RHEL virtual machine vrs. RHEL installed directly on hardware?  Also very useful to know if there is improvement using it vrs. not on a VM?

Comment: did you perform any testing or get more information on this?

Comment: I'm afraid I never got the time.

Comment: I guess I should test myself - I think there should be a difference (not sure how big) since the VM is virtualizing hware access - have to test to figure out how big the difference is

Comment: What were the results?